# Entity Framework Core dbContext behavior after rejecting changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a C# .NET Core API project with Entity Framework.
In one of these APIs, there is a specific case where I need to abort the change I was making in my db context and then save other different data in my database.

I found and edited the code a little to do this:

```
public void RejectChanges()
{
    var ChangeTracker = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker(_context);
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Modified:
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified; //Revert changes made to deleted entity.
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I have a very big doubt: if another API is going to save its own data, does this operation affect also its data, rejecting also those changes? Or, as I wish, does it affect only the API session that called this method?

EXAMPLE: API 1 edits some data in the context, then calls the `RejectChanges` method. Meanwhile, the API 2 edits other data and it's going to save. Does `RejectChanges`, called from API 1 reject also the edits made by API 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Change Tracker is scoped to a single DbContext, which *should* be scoped to a single API request.  Also you don't create a new ChangeTracker.  The DbContext already has one.

```
var ChangeTracker = _context.ChangeTracker;
```

Comment: If you set State back to Unchanged then doesn't it copy the original value of the property back to the current value?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good catch.